# LAG / OVER / PARTITION / ORDER BY using conditions - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

---

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Date            AccountID       Amount
2018-01-01      123             12
2018-01-06      123             150
2018-02-14      123             11
2018-05-06      123             16
2018-05-16      123             200
2018-06-01      123             18
2018-06-15      123             17
2018-06-18      123             110
2018-06-30      123             23
2018-07-01      123             45
2018-07-12      123             116
2018-07-18      123             60
```

This table has multiple dates and IDs, along with multiple Amounts. For each individual row, I want grab the last Date where Amount was over a specific value for that specific AccountID. I have been trying to use the LAG( Date, 1 ) in combination with several variatons of CASE and OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Date ) statements but I've had no luck. Ultimately, this is what I would like my SELECT statement to return.

```
Date            AccountID       Amount          LastOverHundred
2018-01-01      123             12              NULL
2018-01-06      123             150             2018-01-06
2018-02-14      123             11              2018-01-06
2018-05-06      123             16              2018-01-06
2018-05-16      123             200             2018-05-16
2018-06-01      123             18              2018-05-16
2018-06-15      123             17              2018-05-16
2018-06-18      123             110             2018-06-18
2018-06-30      123             23              2018-06-18
2018-07-01      123             45              2018-06-18
2018-07-12      123             116             2018-07-12
2018-07-18      123             60              2018-07-12
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Use a cumulative conditional `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when amount > 100 then date end) over (partition by accountid order by date) as lastoverhundred
from t;
```